# Objective-C iPhone - Playing youtube within an app

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to play youtube using the method described in this url
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application

but with a custom button? (i.e in the picture in the link, it's of a baseball game with the play button overlay on top, I want that to be a custom button that I create)

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

No, the way that you play YouTube videos is by opening it in the mobile site, which takes you to the embedded QuickTime/YouTube viewer. It doesn't play them in the view of your app like the QTView would on a Mac.